# Dart Polymer : Type X is not a subtype of type Y

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I develop my application with Dart and Polymer on PyCharm. I currently have an error :

```
Exception: type 'ObservableList<DrugFilterItem>' is not a subtype of type 'ObservableList<DrugCompareItem>' of '__$orderFilterList@51385934'
ObservableList is from package:observe/src/observable_list.dart
DrugFilterItem is from package:synmed/drug_elements/views/drug_filter_menu.dart
ObservableList is from package:observe/src/observable_list.dart
DrugCompareItem is from package:synmed/drug_elements/views/drug_search_toolbar.dart
```

DrugFilterItem and DrugCompareItem are both custom classes, DrugCompareItem extends DrugFilterItem, and the line designed by the error is :

`ObservableList<DrugCompareItem> orderFilterList = new ObservableList<DrugFilterItem>();`

The problem suddenly happened today : I installed Pycharm 2016.3 and tried to code, but I had an error with the package shadow, which I solved. Since, I have this error which I supposed came from a problem with the packages as the code didn't change from before to after.

What I have found for now is nothing in fact, I read a lot of post on this kind of error, one of the recurrent subject was the imports but I didn't find any problem with this. I am using Dart 1.20.1 and

```
polymer: "<=0.16.4+1"
core_elements: "<=0.7.1+3"
paper_elements: "<=0.7.1"
```

Do anyone has any clue for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/14972#issuecomment-108402835

> I believe this is working as intended. A List is not assignable to a List, even if it only contains Apples.
>
> There are several ways to work around this:
>
> ```
> iterable.map((x) => x) (removing the generic type),
> new List<MethodMirror>.from(iterable)
> new MyIterableWrapper<MethodMirror>(iterable) (where the iterable-wrapper that would need to be written).
> ```

Comment: I understand this, I just don't understand why this kind of error just pop out suddently as it was working before my problem with smoke package. Couldn't it be linked?

Comment: Could it be a bug in older versions that only is reported after updating the SDK. Perhaps you didn't run in checked mode before. Types are ignored in production mode.

Comment: I confirm I didn't run it in checked mode. Then I will have to make this change for all my errors. Thank you for your time!

Comment: For my personnal knowledge, I start my application with `pub serve`, how can I toogle checked mode and production mode? I'm searching but hasn't figured out yet. If I am not wrong, the default mode is now checked?!

Comment: Dartium takes a command line flag (configuration in WebStorm for example) for the mode and is "production" by default AFAIR  and dart2js (for Chrome, Firefox, ...) only supports "production" mode with `pub serve` because "checked" mode was too slow.

Comment: Ah ok I undertand. Just for information if someone has the same problem. I figured out that PyCharm 2016.2.3 has an option to lauch in checked mode or not and Pycharm 2016.3 doesn't have it. That's why I came in that situation after upgrading. Finaly I understand where it all comes from. Thanks again Günter!